# Faster way than map with includes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

I have the following example scenario:

```js
var exampleArrayObjects = [{name: 'Example1'}, {name: 'Example2'}, {name: 'Example3'}];
var exampleArrayValues = ['Example1'];


var result = exampleArrayObjects.map((obj) => {
    if(exampleArrayValues.includes(obj.name)){
        return {
            ...obj,
            selected: true
        } 
    }else{
        return {
            ...obj,
            selected: false
        }
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

But in real life scenario, with large amount of data on "exampleArrayObjects" and "exampleArrayValues" it is taking a few minutes to get the result (a result object with additional attribute selected true/false according to the existance of the value).

Is there a faster way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead for sublinear search times.

```js
const exampleArrayObjects = [{name: 'Example1'}, {name: 'Example2'}, {name: 'Example3'}];
const exampleArrayValues = new Set(['Example1']);
const res = exampleArrayObjects.map(o => ({...o, selected: exampleArrayValues.has(o.name)}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code checks for the presence of each object's `name` property in the `exampleArrayValues` array, which implies an algorithm complexity of roughly O(n^2), where n is the length of `exampleArrayObjects`. This could lead to performance issues when both arrays are large.

To optimize this, you could convert `exampleArrayValues` into a Set and then use this Set for lookups. Since the time complexity of lookup operation for Set is O(1), this will significantly reduce the overall complexity of the algorithm to O(n):

```
var exampleArrayObjects = [{name: 'Example1'}, {name: 'Example2'}, {name: 'Example3'}];
var exampleArrayValues = ['Example1'];

// Convert into Set
var exampleSet = new Set(exampleArrayValues);

var result = exampleArrayObjects.map((obj) => {
    return {
        ...obj,
        selected: exampleSet.has(obj.name)
    }
})

console.log(result);
```